# why when i upload file and click on more to upload another file the first one delete?

Tags: javascript, html

why when i upload file and click on more to upload another file the first one delete?

```
 <table align="right" border="1" cellpadding="2">
       <tr>
      <td class="auto-style45" id="theadder"><input type="file" name="the_file_24">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<br><br></td>
      <td>Here you<br> can upload <br>your files<br>
      <span align="right" style="cursor:pointer;" id="adduploadinput" onclick="javascript:addInput('theadder')">more+</span>
      </td>
     </tr>
</table>

    <!--this the javascript function thats add more files-->
 <script>
    var inc=1;
    function addInput(x){
    document.getElementById(x).innerHTML += "<input id=filee"+inc+" type=file name=the_file_24>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;  <br><br>";
        inc++;
 }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from pretty badly written HTML, your problem is here:

name=the_file_24

add the +inc part to the name as you did for the id and take that into account on your receiving code and it should work.

As it is all your file inputs have the same name so they overwrite each other.

Comment: can you show me example? or link that explains how to upload file?